# ¿Como convertir un columna date de un .csv a entero en Python?

Tags: python, jupyter, spyder

**Esto es lo que llevo de codigo, pero deseo que al momento de imprimir print(fecha_a_entero) me de como resultado toda la columna que converti (con sus registros)  **

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
from datetime import datetime
from sklearn.linear_model  import LinearRegression 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

datos=pd.read_csv('us-counties.csv',header=0)
print("DATASET ={}".format(datos))
df = pd.DataFrame(datos,columns= ['deaths','county','state','date'])
print("Columnas que voy a usar={}".format(df))
from datetime import datetime
micadena=datos['date']
print(micadena)

def fecha_a_entero(micadena):
    date_new=datetime.strptime(micadena, '%Y-%m-%d')
    return 10000*date_new.year+100*date_new.month+date_new.day
print(fecha_a_entero)

columnlista = datos['date'].tolist()
print(columnlista)
def columna_a_entero(columna_lista):
    lista_enteros=list(map(fecha_a_entero,columnlist))
    return lista_enteros
print (columna_a_entero)
```

Comment: Pega como siempre con `ctrl+v`. Selecciona luego el texto y `ctrl+k` lo conviertes en código. Por favor, edita la pregunta para que esté más clara (y borra el autocomentario).

Comment: Hola CheaCortes, gracias por la ayuda y la paciencia, como podes ver soy nuevo y hasta ahora interactuo en este espacio y desconozco muchas cosas que me impiden aprender ya que al ver que no cumplo con los conocimientos de los demas me reportan la pregunta y me la borran..no hay tolerancia

Comment: pero como seria mas clara, estoy en la busqueda de usar mi columna de mi .csv convertida en entero es decir que toda esa columna venga con su 261070 registros pero en formato numerico con sus 8 numeros, es decir 2020-01-01 sea (20200101)

Comment: Muestra los resultados de la ejecucion. Si son muchos datos, acortalos. bastaria con unos 10 elementos de cada lista.

Comment: Hola Candi Moe gracias por la buena ayuda. Te comento ya pude solucionar, aprovechando puedo hacerte una consulta? ¿Como puedo compartir un proyecto para que se pueda visualizar?